# How can I override the session ID for a node.js express session (using passport)

Tags: node.js, express, session, node.js-connect

I'm implementing a passport strategy that calls our internal auth service.  The internal auth service generates the session ID, so I need to make sure the connect session uses that ID instead of the default generated ID.

Is there a way to do this?  Is it possible to provide my own hook function to connect to produce the session id?  I can't imagine it's as simple as setting session.id or anything like that, because I don't have control over when or how connect actually creates the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with the current implementation of Connect's session middleware, but you can fork the session middleware and change how the session id is generated, namely this line:

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/session.js#L202

By "fork" I mean copying the file above, changing the assignment of the sessionID and using your new file instead when configuring the session middleware.

UPDATE:

Here's how I would regenerate the session with a custom id (note - this is just an idea, I haven't tested it):

```
// this is the function you'll be calling in your routes or whatever
req.regenerateSession = function(newSid) {
  // keep old session data
  var oldSessionData = req.session;

  // destroy current session and make a new one with your custom id
  store.destroy(req.sessionID, function() {
    store.generate(req, newSid);

    // copy back the session data
    // since you don't want to lose it probably
    req.session = oldSessionData;
  });
}

// replace the session store generate function to accept a custom sessionID
// https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/session.js#L201
store.generate = function(req, customID) {
  req.sessionID = customID || utils.uid(24);
  req.session = new Session(req);
  req.session.cookie = new Cookie(req, cookie);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Instead of forking the file, would the following work as well?

Comment: I think you forgot to paste something.. ? Following what?

Comment: Sorry - enter key submits.  Thank you.  I'm unclear on how I could obtain the custom ID if I forked that file and changed that line, though.  I would only have the custom ID after calling the auth service with login credentials, and I believe that occurs after the session is created.  Could you elaborate on how the solution would work?  My idea was to replace req.session.save inside the passport strategy, that provides the session id from the closure.  i.e. req.session.save = function(fn){ this.req.sessionStore.set(authServiceId, this, fn || function(){});
  return this; }

Comment: The other half of that hack would be to set req.sessionID to the custom session Id as well, so the cookie is created with the same value that the session store saves it under.  These two override steps would only occur during the login call - after that the browser would submit the overridden session ID, which would exist in the session store.  However, I don't know the inner workings of connect - do you think this approach, albeit a hack, would work?

Comment: I posted an update on my answer on how I would do it, hope that helps (haven't actually tried it)